# C# Object doesnt support FirstOrDefault() depending on the input parameter

Tags: c#, linq, dapper

I don't know why the return value of the LoadData function (shown below) in one case supports the FirstOrDefault() method and in another case doesn't. In both cases it is the same return type.

The only difference is the way in which the dynamic parameter is created.

```
    public async Task<LookupModel?> UpdateLookup(LookupModel item, Guid newUk)
        var p1 = new
        {
            item.Code,
            item.Name,
            item.uk,
            newUk
        };

        var result1 = await _db.LoadData<LookupModel, dynamic>("lu.Lookup_Update", p1);
                // result1.GetType() = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DataAccess.Models.Lookups.LookupModel]
        var rtv1 = result1.FirstOrDefault();        // ok


        var p2 = item.GetUpdateParams(newUk);
        
        var result2 = await _db.LoadData<LookupModel, dynamic>("lu.Lookup_Update", p2);
                // result2.GetType() = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DataAccess.Models.Lookups.LookupModel]

        var rtv2 = result2.FirstOrDefault();        // not ok
                                                    // This throws an exception as FirstOrDefault() is not defined

        return rtv1;
    }

    // LookupModel
    public dynamic GetUpdateParams(Guid newUk)
    {
        return new
        {
            this.Code,
            this.Name,
            this.uk,
            newUK
        };
    }

    // LoadData
    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> LoadData<T, U>(string storedProcedure, U parameters, string connectionId = "Default")
    {
        using IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString(connectionId));
        return await connection.QueryAsync<T>(storedProcedure, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

    }
```

Comment: Because p1 is of a concrete type, whereas p2 is of type object (at runtime). So at run time,  LoadData will be generic over the anonymous type or object respectively. Since object does not have any properties, that fails.

Comment: Does it throw an exception or give you a compiler error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p2` is `dynamic`, which means that `result2` is also dynamic (since it takes `p2` as an input), and `FirstOrDefault` is an extension method. Since the type of `result2` is not known at compile time, you can't call an extension method on it.

You can still do this by using the actual static method instead of an extension method:

```
var rtv2 = Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(result2);
```

since the static method *can* be bound at run-time.

But I would just change `GetUpdateParams` so that it returns a named type rather than an anonymous type, and then you don't have to use `dynamic`. That will also get you more type safety since the compiler can do type checking and you don't have to wait until runtime to find type errors.

Comment: That makes sense. I was thinking that p1 was also dynamic, and couldn't understand the different behavior, but I see now that p1 is an anonymous type. `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(result2)` worked, but your suggestion about a named type sounds a better approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Because p1 is of a concrete type, whereas p2 is of type object (at runtime). So at run time, LoadData will be generic over the anonymous type or object respectively. Since object does not have any properties, that fails.

I suggest that to fix this you clone p2 to a concrete anonymous type before calling LoadData

```
Parameters p2clone = new { Code = p2.Code...};
var bar = LoadData(p2clone);

interface Parameters 
{
    string Code {get;}
    string Name {get;}
    ...
}
```

The reason you need to do this is that Linq Expression compilers use reflection heavily on the types that are passed in. Without the type info, dapper isn't able to compile your SQL.

Comment: `p2` is `dynamic`, so `p2clone` will be dynamic as well, which will still prevent the extension method from being called.

Comment: @DStanley Damn, nice catch. I forgot that the properties of p2 are unknown at compile time.

Comment: Yeah dynamics are tricky - you don't realize you've bypassed type safety until runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Remove await from this line

```
//var result1 = await _db.LoadData<LookupModel, dynamic>("lu.Lookup_Update", p1);
var result1 = _db.LoadData<LookupModel, dynamic>("lu.Lookup_Update", p1);
```

Change

```
var rtv1 = result1.FirstOrDefault();
```

to

```
var rtv1= await result1.FirstOrDefaultAsync()
```

The namespace that belongs to `FirstorDefaultAsync()` should be added.